# Dell XPS 13 Plus 9320 - Bluetooth mouse and sometimes touchpad freeze - Firmware up to date

Tags: touchpad, xps, firmware

My device was built on October 15th, and the Touchpad Firmware update from Dell is from September, regardless, I have updated in Windows the Firmware but the tools seems to do nothing, maybe because it is already up to date.

Where can I check in Ubuntu or Windows the current Firmware version for the Touchpad?